# Primefaces - Get files in alphabetical order in multiple file upload component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using [Primefaces Multiple file upload component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) in an application. Here i choose 'n' number of files and clicked on upload button. Then i need to get each files in `fileUploadListener`  according to alphabetical order. How it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the multiple file upload component is a [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin, the default state is not sequential, that means all the files get upload asynchronously.

To get the component to do a sequential upload, you have to set `sequentialUploads` to true, and on change we do a little alphabetical sorting of the current files. all this is done by javascript.

Assuming your widgetVar is `fileUploadWV`

```
<p:fileUpload widgetVar="fileUploadWV"
              fileUploadListener="#{attachmentBean.onUpload}" />

<script>
   $(function() {
      // setTimeout waits till the widgetVar is ready!
      setTimeout(sortFileUpload, 2000);
   });

   function sortFileUpload() {
      //Set this option to true to issue all file upload requests in a sequential order instead of simultaneous requests.  
      PF('fileUploadWV').jq.data().blueimpFileupload.options.sequentialUploads = true;

      //every time a new file is added, sort the files based on name
      PF('fileUploadWV').jq.change(function() {
          PF('fileUploadWV').files.sort(function fileSort(a, b) {
           return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
          })
      });
   }
</script>
```

So in this scenario your files would get uploaded in an alphabetical order.

Note: if you don't set sequentialUploads into true, you have no control which file is going to be sent first.

[Github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/fileUpload/sequentialUploads.xhtml), [Online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/fileUpload/sequentialUploads.xhtml)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried doing this and it worked (when it comes to performing sequential requests) but the final outcome results in only one file got actually uploaded (processed by the `fileUploadListener`). Do you have any suggestion for all `fileUploadListener`s to get called?

Comment: Also, it seems this is turning into a feature https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/403

Comment: @nuno I didn't get you exactly. The answer I posted was tested for multiple uploads, and for each file the the listener was called, maybe something else is not working for you ?

Comment: Perhaps it is an unrelated issue - I'll check further

Comment: I'll test my code again, which PF version are you using ? @nuno

Comment: I'm using PF 5.2 and JSF 2.2

Comment: The answer might help you more now. Note: I'm testing with JSF 2.1, but I don't think that this would be the problem you are having...  Check the online demo @nuno

Comment: In PF 5, I am geting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jq' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

yes, but this solution is not very elegant:

```
<p:remoteCommand action="#{attachmentBean.processAttachments}" 
    name="processAttachments" update="attachmentTable"/>  

<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{attachmentBean.onUpload}" 
    oncomplete="processAttachments()" />
```

`attachmentBean.onUpload` stores each file inside a List/Map/SortedMap
`attachmentBean.processAttachments` eventually sorts that List/Map and process attachments in order

`attachmentBean` must be at least `@ViewScoped`